# How do you determine the app store (country) availability of an iOS application given its App ID?

Tags: ios, app-store

How do you determine the app store (country) availability of an iOS application given its App ID? Some have posted asking a similar question but "inside" an app.  I'm looking for the answer "outside" of the app like on a standard browser.  I know that a brute force way of doing it is to just parse every country code out there and see if it returns some data, but I'm looking for a way to do it in a more strategic way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

A typical App Store URL looks like this:
http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id494732564

Just replace the "us" with another country code to see if its available in that country, including any localizations. For example, the same app above in German (de): http://itunes.apple.com/de/app/id494732564

Hope this doesn't your definition of "brute force".

Comment: This is exactly what OP said he didn't want to do.

Comment: The OP mentioned wanting to do it outside the app in a browser, so that's what I showed him. Go easy on the downvotes!

Comment: Yes, in a browser, but not brute forcing every country code.  Is what you are saying different than that?

Comment: I guess it depends on OP's definition of "brute force", and what the objective is. I think it should be the OP's call whether my suggestion is brute force, and would hope that you reconsider the down vote.

Comment: Ok, fair enough, it is a bit ambiguous so I will give you the benefit of the doubt ^^ (But it looks like I can't cancel it yet...)

Comment: I cannot remove the down vote unless you edit the question, just so you know :-S

Comment: Actually the problem with this is when there's an app that ONLY releases to a certain country, e.g. CA or AU ONLY, it will not work without the country code in the URL.  I've tried this myself.  So I'm wondering instead of looping through all country codes, is there another way to get that list?

Comment: Example:  http://itunes.apple.com/ca/app/id520359912    http://itunes.apple.com/app/id520359912

Comment: A command line tool would be great. They also have an API. Wondering if it has this information too.